# Failed to bind properties under 'server' to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties:

Tags: spring-boot

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-09-04 12:23:24.383 ERROR 12320 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'server' to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties:

    Property: server
    Value: 
    Origin: class path resource [application.properties]:2:0
    Reason: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties]

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

My application.properties file look like this:

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:9191}

spring:

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://PC382682:1433;databaseName=imvenkat 
    username: imvenkat
    password: imvenkat
    driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

I know the issue is related to Spring boot, but how should I change my application.properties file to address this issue?

Comment: are you sure the property file name is application.properties but not application.yml?

Comment: @Alien I was about to ask that as well, but considering that the error message mentions `application.properties`, I think you can safely assume that he really did name it that way (and not `application.yml`).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're using YAML format within a properties file. The properties are being parsed line by line, so the properties parser reads `server:`, and doesn't know how to bind to `server` directly, which causes the error you see.

Either rename your file to `application.yml` or change the properties:

```
server.port=${PORT:9191}

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://PC382682:1433;databaseName=imvenkat 
spring.datasource.username=imvenkat
spring.datasource.password=imvenkat
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Comment: Failed to auto-configure a DataSource: 'spring.datasource.url' is not specified and no embedded datasource could be auto-configured.

Comment: @Venkady Make sure that you have no typo in `spring.datasource.url` in `application.properties`.

Comment: @Venkady I have no clue then. Can you create a new question (this seems to be a new issue) with the `application.properties` you have now and a full error description?

Answer (score 2):

This Error can occur when there is mis match between parent version and your spring-boot-devtools dependency.

Remove the version from spring-boot-devtools dependency, that will solve the issue.

`<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if your config file is in yaml format but you have an error in your yaml so one line looks like a property. Happened to me, previous this was just a broken configuration line, now it breaks the application.

So if you have something broken (look at the url=) like:

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:9191}

spring:

  datasource:
    url=jdbc:sqlserver://PC382682:1433;databaseName=imvenkat
```

the same cryptic error can occur. Fixing the config line fixes this error.